# Get Profile Name and Photo of all AD users from AD using CSOM

Tags: 2013, user-profile, ad

I want to get all the AD users profile name and photo directly from AD using CSOM. Is there any way to do this without getting from user profile service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SharePoint Client Side Object Model is for SharePoint, not Active Directory. If you want to get info directly from AD you need to use a different approach.